# Is it possible to make a halfbridge coilgun with high side IGBT and low side SCRs?

Tags: coil, igbt, thyristor, scr, half-bridge

In a rather simple coilgun, the problem of freewheeling current from the coil is solved with a diode in parallel with the coil.

The energy of the reverse current is wasted this way and even slows the projectile most of the time since there is current flowing after it is shut off.

A more advanced approach would be the usage of a half bridge system, where the current can flow back to the capacitor instead of being dumped into the diode.

When using multiple stages, you of course only need one IGBT or MOSFET for the highside:

[image]

This also allows me to control when the stages are switched off, but I need a drive circuit for each IGBT on the low side and it is also very costly in practice because I would need many high current and high voltage IGBTs.

Is it possible to use SCRs instead of IGBTs or MOSFETs for the low side?

The SCRs have a turn on time of a few microseconds, so they should turn on only a small time after the high side IGBT.

My concern would be that the reverse current flows through the SCR instead back to the capacitor.  Is there a way to change that?

EDIT: in the schematic, D5 is connected backwards, its supposed to be the other way around!

Comment: You might want to look at the two-switch flyback/forward topology. SCRs are only useful if the capacitors can be made resonant (not exactly a good idea with electrolytics).

Comment: I don’t think there is much energy accumulated in coils since they are air-cored.

Comment: There definitly is a high current pulse of several hundred amps after the switch off, which, when it gets slowly drained off through a diode, slows the projectile.

Comment: @kall please explain why multiple stages are needed.

Comment: The Max velocity of a Single stage is limited, because more windings will increase the on time of the coil, eventually pulling the projectile back

Comment: @TimWilliams isn't the two-switch flyback/forward topology the one that I showed in the schematic?

Comment: Nearly: D5 is backwards, and you need one each (pair of transistors and diodes per coil).  @MichalPodmanický peak currents are generally as high as possible for these projects; hundreds of amperes can pack quite a wallop even in a few uH. Evidently this will be a linear reluctance motor, so the energy delivered to the armature is a fraction of the energy stored in the magnetic field.

Comment: @TimWilliams why do i need two per stage? thanks for mentioning d5

Comment: Well what else are you gonna do, you can't discharge all the coils at once AND discharge them one at a time, right?

Comment: @TimWilliams Well, the low-side switches have different time periods when they get turned on and off, the high-side turns on and off equally with every low-side switch, allowing the current of the capacitor to only run through one coil each. My question is if it can also be achieved with low-side scrs.

Comment: Ohh, non-overlapping, that would make all the difference! You still need MOS since current would be continuous into the SCR, no reason for it to ever turn off or reverse. At least until the capacitor reverses of course, but that can't happen with all these diodes clamping it.